# RISCV Instruction set simulator

Tags: mips, cpu, simulator, riscv, instruction-set

I'm look for instruction set simulator for CPU based on RISC-V.
I want to observe the hazard on different CPUs (RISCV and MIPS).

This example is for MIPS.

```
lw r1,A(r2)
lw r3,B(r4)
dadd r5,r1,r3
beq r5,r5,L1 
sw r5,A(r3)
L1: sw r5,B(r4)
```

`beq` must be stall (wait for r5)

Do you suggest any software simulator?
I can write some instructions to simulate.
For MIPS, I use WinMIPS64 (http://indigo.ie/~mscott/).

Answer (score 0):

The canonical instruction set simulator for RISC-V is here https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-sim

It does not highlight dependencies because it is not modeling a specific CPU but just modeling the ISA.

Answer (score 0):

[Ripes](https://github.com/mortbopet/Ripes) is a graphical processor simulator and assembly editor for the RISC-V ISA.  Its current version (ver. 2.2.3) has different versions of the RISC-V processor (single-cycle, 5-stage w/o forwarding or hazard detection, 5-stage w/ forwarding but w/o hazard detection, 5-stage w/ hazard detection but w/o forwarding, 5-stage w/ forwarding and hazard detection, 6-stage dual-issue).  Both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of these are supplied.